# GoJS nested shape positioning

Tags: javascript, gojs

I am trying to draw nested shapes with GoJS library. For now I have rectangle with a single line inside.
Whole Object is a panel with two shapes, a rectangle and a minus line. At this point it is fine, MinusLine is rendered in the center of a rectangle.

What I want to achieve is to position/change location of a MinusLine from top to bottom and etc. based on some conditions that I got however I cannot move it in any way.
For example move perfectly centered YELLOW line to position of RED or BROWN 
[image]

Code looks like:

```
GO(go.Node, "Table",
    {
        layerName: "AfterForeground",
        movable: false,
        locationObjectName: "BODY",
        locationSpot: go.Spot.parse("0.5 0 0 0 "),
        selectionObjectName: "MAIN_SHAPE",
        selectionObjectName: "MAIN_SHAPE",
    },
    new go.Binding("location", "loc", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),

    GO(go.Panel,go.Panel.Position, "Auto", {
        row: 1,
        column: 1,
        name: "BODY",
        stretch: go.GraphObject.Fill
    },
        GO(go.Shape, "Rectangle", {
            fill: wellColor,
            name: "MAIN_SHAPE",
            stroke: myColor,
            strokeWidth: 0.4,

        }, new go.Binding("fill", "wellColor"),
        ) , new go.Binding("desiredSize", "size", go.Size.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Size.stringify)
        ,GO(go.Shape, "MinusLine", {}), // <-- Move this YELLOW line vertically somehere inside Rectangle 
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is a Table panel (for the Node's Panel type) really what you want?

So far you have a Table panel that has a single cell, and by default all objects in the cell will sit in the center. You can easily move them by adding the `alignment` property to the elements.

Here's an example of your table, with two sub-panels added to the Node, one aligned to the top, one aligned to the center with a y offset of 30:
https://codepen.io/simonsarris/pen/zYBrLaX?editors=1011

There are other positioning examples for Table panel, here:

https://gojs.net/latest/intro/tablePanels.html

https://gojs.net/latest/intro/tablePanels.html#StretchAndAlignmente

Note that as you have defined the template, the Shape takes up the entire space of the table, with a minus line in the center of the shape. This is probably not what you want. I put a width and height on the Shape and a (bigger) height on the table to make the demonstration legibile.